# Type react component with changeable wrapper and wrapper props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Learning TypeScript.
I'm trying add types to react component which accepts wrapper component and forward rest of the props to wrapper component. But getting following error:

```
Type 'Pick<DirectProps<WrapperProps> & WrapperProps, Exclude<keyof WrapperProps, "as">> & { children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & WrapperProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Pick<DirectProps<WrapperProps> & WrapperProps, Exclude<keyof WrapperProps, "as">> & { children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'WrapperProps'.
    'WrapperProps' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Pick<DirectProps<WrapperProps> & WrapperProps, Exclude<keyof WrapperProps, "as">> & { children: string; }'
```

Which I'm not able to solve.

Minimal example:

```
interface DirectProps<Props = unknown> {
  as?: string | React.ComponentType<Props>;
}

function GenericComponent<Props = unknown>({
  as: Component = "div",
  ...props
}: DirectProps<Props> & Props): JSX.Element {
  return <Component {...props}>Here goes children</Component>;
}
```

Which is used like that:

```
{/* Render as div */}
<GenericComponent onClick={() => console.log("Click")} />

{/* Render as link */}
<GenericComponent<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>
  as="a"
  href="https://stackoverflow.com"
  target="_blank"
/>
```

I prepared codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-hofstadter-2zzbe?file=/src/App.tsx

I'll be eternally grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to build a generic component. I would suggest having atomic components. Your code will be more readable and easier to debug if the responsibilities of each component does one thing well. Ask yourself: What problem am I trying to solve exactly? How readable and debuggable is my code? Do I save myself any "thought complexity" by implementing generic components? How would I unit test these components?

Take the following atomic components, for example:

```
// components/Links.tsx

export function A(props: React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
  return (<a {...props} style={{ ...customStylesOrWhatever }} />)
}
export function LinkToHome() {
  return <A href="/home">Home</A>
}
export function LinkToSettings() {
  return <A href="/settings">Settings</A>
}

// "Dumb" components:
<LinkToHome />
<LinkToSettings />
<A href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">StackOverflow</A>
```

Imagine, for a moment, looking for a specific component in a tree full of `GenericComponent`. Personally, as a colleague, I would be super bummed out. In applications with thousands of components this would require significant "brain RAM". With atomic responsibilities, this becomes a trivial task. This is a decision on Composition vs. Configuration where Composition is typically preferred in React apps.

Comment: While it doesn’t answer the original question I’m thankful to you for making me thinking if I really need that broadly configurable wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you always pass a string to the props `as`, so we can change the interface to:

```
interface DirectProps {
  as?: string;
}
```

after that we can change the function to

```
function GenericComponent<Props = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>({
  as: Component = "div",
  ...props
}: DirectProps & Props): JSX.Element {
  return <Component {...props}/>;
}
```

Then the error goes away in the code sandbox you set up.

Part of it complaining was that you are adding your own children in the `Component`. The children would be automatically passed down through `...props`

Comment: I’m wondering why it helps. Does constraining `Props` helps or something else. Switching `as` to string is not an option as it could be react router `Link`